# Bootstrap Group Button and text but with space between them

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue

Hello I want the text and button I have to be on a single line instead of underneath each other. First I did this with

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"><p>Document2.pdf</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button></div><br>
```

But this put the button and the text right next to each other with no spacing. So instead of **btn-group** I used **btn-toolbar** but this put the items underneath each other.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"><p>Document1.pdf</p><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button></div><br>
```

I tried adding **flex-wrap: nowrap** but this didn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this problem and properly align them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `margin-right`.

**OPTION 1 (recommended): Use the Bootstrap class (e.g., `me-3`)**

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <p class="me-3">Document2.pdf</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
</div>
```

**OPTION 2: Use CSS**

See the snippet below.

```css
p {
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <p>Document2.pdf</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "spacing" mean to you? Margin creates spacing.

Comment: This works thanks! I accepted your answer

Comment: I forgot to edit something in my code therefore I thought it did not work but it does, so my bad

Comment: No worries, everything is fine. :)